# Extract grouped text from image with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

When I want to extract and localize text from an image in python I know I can use OCR libraries like `pytesseract`. What I have seen on the web though: Every word is extracted separately, the engine doesn't detect which words belong together.

Let's say I have an image with sentences / text blocks distributed over it. Those are far enough apart from each other that they are easily recognizable as separate.

How can I extract those word groups into a list of lists? For example, if I have `"Hello World"` in the top left corner, and `"Foo bar"` in the bottom right. Then I want my function to return `[["Hello", "world"], ["Foo", "bar"]]`

EDIT: This would be my manual approach, if there is no builtin function / more elegant way to achieve this:

https://fahmisalman.medium.com/an-easy-way-of-creating-text-localization-and-detection-in-tesseract-ocr-24cc89ed6fbc

Then I would calculate the minimum distance between each pair of bounding boxes, and then decide which belong together using some algorithm (for example, put the distances in a list and compute the 0.8 quantile, and then group all words together that are less than 1/5 from this distance away from each other. Numbers would need fine-tuning, of course).

I am asking this because I can't believe nothing like this exists already (extracting sentences or phrases from an image instead of single words doesn't sound too unusual to me). I don't want to reinvent the wheel unnecessarily.

EDIT: here is an image of my example:

[image: example image]

Comment: As you should know, StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service. Edit the code of your honest attempt to solve this problem into your question, provide the input image and explain hat you expect your code should produce and what it actually produces.

Comment: @balmy I know. I am asking to see if somebody has an elegant approach or an OCR library has a function like this built-in and I missed it. I don't think the problem is that special (extracting sentences from an image as sentences instead of single words sounds like something everybody using OCR libraries would come across sooner or later). Anyways, adding what would be the manual approach if nothing like this exists already. I don't want to reinvent the wheel though.

Comment: Maybe, you would like to add an example image?

Comment: @Ahx I have added an image now.